# How do I fetch my git repository from SourceForge?

Tags: git, sourceforge

My git repository is currently on Sourceforge, I've just reinstalled Ubuntu and I want to continue working on my repository, but I can't figure how to do it, could someone give me some really easy instructions? (I'm very new to git)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install git git-core` and you should be good to go. ;-)

Comment: What do I do next? I want to get again to the point where I can just enter the directory, add, commit and push.

Comment: Visit the sourceproject project page in your browser and go to its "code" page. You should now be able to see the exact clone command to use with the address of the project git address of the project. Something similar to `git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/<project-name>`. Run that command on your PC to fetch the project and you are good to go.

Comment: It works, I hope I won't be able to mess up when I try to commit the first time, thanks!

Comment: Ensure while running `git clone` that you use a URL with write access. Otherwise you will **not** be able to `git push origin` later.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist
My sourceforge project page does not have such a link. No information whatsoever. It's an old project. Maybe that's why?

Comment: IIRC, it also depends on whether "Git hosting" feature was chosen when creating the project.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ sudo apt-get install git # do this once, to install git
$ git clone git://PROJECT.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/PROJECT/PROJECT
```

You'll have to substitute your project name obviously, and maybe one of the tokens will be slightly different for you, depending on what your project is.  Probably you can find the exact URL to clone on your project page itself.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to have worked. And after this, can I just enter the directory, then add, commit and push? I would test, but I didn't make any modification yet. Do I still need to set the origin and things like this? I remember doing something like this when I started the repository, but I am clueless now.

Comment: The origin is set automatically when you clone, so you do not need to set it.  The only other thing you probably need to set before committing is your name and email, and git commit itself will remind you how to do that the first time you commit (so I won't bother detailing the commands here).

Comment: Wont this fetch a read-only copy to the local machine? Shouldn't we be using the http URL so that we have write access (`git push origin`) as well later on? Hmmm?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: I'm not sure about that--I'm not a SourceForge expert.  But if the origin needs to be changed later, it's no problem--just edit it in the `.git/config` file in the local project root.

Answer (score 7):

In 2018 the format looks more like this now:

```
https://git.code.sf.net/p/[PROJECTNAME]/[REPOSITORY]/
```

Where `[PROJECTNAME]` is your project name ([Source](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Git/#anonymous-access-read-only)), and `[REPOSITORY]` is repo name, usually defaulting to '*code*'.